# Google Calendar "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel" error

Tags: curl, oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to set-up push notifications with Google Calendar. Currently I'm using the [oAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) to get a feel for how it works. So I've selected Calendar API v3, authorised it, used the authorisation code and access token provided and querying the following URI: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/tl7grdo4gqdqj4gtanpioksi6k@group.calendar.google.com/events/watch. The request contains the following body:

> `{
>     "id": "154345345-345345345", 
>     "type": "web_hook",
>     "address": "https://www.somedomain.com/web_hook.php"
>   }`

I have added the domain to webmaster tools to prove ownership and also added it to the "allowed domains" list within the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Sending the following request:

> `POST /calendar/v3/calendars/tl7grdo4gqdqj4gtanpioksi6k@group.calendar.google.com/events/watch HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.googleapis.com
>   Content-length: 105
>   Content-type: application/json
>   Authorization: Bearer <some access token>
>   {
>      "id": "154345345-345345345", 
>      "type": "web_hook",
>      "address": "https://www.somedomain.com/web_hook.php"
>   }`

Produces the following response:

> `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   Content-length: 318
>   X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
>   X-content-type-options: nosniff
>   Expires: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 13:22:51 GMT
>   Server: GSE
>   Cache-control: private, max-age=0
>   Date: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 13:22:51 GMT
>   X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
>   Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>   Www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token
>   {
>     "error": {
>       "code": 401, 
>       "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://www.somedomain.com/web_hook.php", 
>       "errors": [
>         {
>           "domain": "global", 
>           "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://www.somedomain.com/web_hook.php", 
>           "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }`

I'm hoping to get some very basic but specific steps I need to follow to get this functioning correctly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: possibly a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928758/google-push-notifications-unauthorized-webhook-callback-channel

Comment: Now the general problem is clearer in my head, it's very similar but the crux of the problem seems to be the OAuth playground itself as I've managed to get it working with my own code. When I get home from work I plan to better investigate the issue and offer some guidance to whoever stumbles across this question in their travels.

Comment: I tried getting this working on my production code and still can't solve this issue :(

Answer (score 7):

Evidently the [oAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) simply doesn't have a handle on the domains added via the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/) in order to verify the provided webhook has been authorised. I managed to get it working with code which seemed to the follow the same steps as the playground.