# push.webhookUrlUnauthorized error

Tags: flask, google-drive-realtime-api, ngrok, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to use the drive API to test watching one of my google drive's documents...

I have created a localhost server using python flask...

This is my code for it

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def display():
    user = {'nickname': 'Miguel'}  # fake user
        return '''
        <html>
            <head>
                    <title>Home Page</title>
                <meta name="google-site-verification" content="XXXX" />
            </head>
            <body>
                    <h1>Hello, ''' + user['nickname'] + '''</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
     '''
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()

@app.route('/hello', METHODS=['POST'])
def hello():
    return request.get_data()
```

I use ngrok to connect my localhost to the internet...

This doesn't even matter however because the drive API cannot connect to the server

as when I use the Google Drive API in the API explorer it gives me

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://44c689c2.ngrok.io"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://44c689c2.ngrok.io"
 }
}
```

The items that I put into the body are:

```
{
"address":"https://44c689c2.ngrok.io",
"type":"web_hook",
"id":"abc123"
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You have the same issue in this [post](http://www.magicsite.cn/a102-11644-push-notification).

> To use [Push Notifications](http://www.magicsite.cn/a102-11644-push-notification) in Google Calendar make sure you
>   followed the instructions here:
>
> 1. Register the domain of your receiving URL in Google Dev Console. Go to Credentials and click Domain Verification for the webhook setup.
>
> [image]
>
> For example, if you plan to use
>   `https://yourdomainexample.com/notifications` as your receiving URL,
>   you need to register `https://yourdomainexample.com`. Set up your
>   receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.
>
> 2. This is an HTTPS server that handles the API notification messages that are triggered when a resource changes.
> 3. Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch.
>
> A channel specifies routing information for notification messages. As
>   part of the channel setup, you identify the specific URL where you
>   want to receive notifications. Whenever a channel's resource changes,
>   the Google Calendar API sends a notification message as a POST request
>   to that URL.

You may also check this this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156523/google-calendar-api-push-notification-401-unauthorized-webhook-callback-chann).