# Google Admin SDK - watch users with Let's Encrypt secured endpoint

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm doing PoC of some GSuite custom solution which needs to listen to changes on `users` resource. I've created a GSuite account, linked it (and verified) with *`mytestdomain.com`*. It's also verified in API console. Basically followed instructions from https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push
and fulfilled all requirements from there.

Unfortunately when I try to register my web hook I'm getting following error:

```
Watch request denied by backend [403]
Errors [
    Message[Watch request denied by backend] Location[ - ] Reason[watchDenied] Domain[push]
]
```

I stuck with it and don't know where too look for more details about that error. 
I'm using a certificate generated by Let's encrypt, but tested it with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and got rank `A`. How to check if Google API treats Let's Encrypt as trusted CA?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928758/google-push-notifications-unauthorized-webhook-callback-channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem wasn't anyhow related to Let's Encrypt certificates. They're working just fine with Google's push notifications. I've contacted with Google support and with their help I've established that sending a request with `showDeleted` parameter set to true was a root cause of above problem.

Support guy claimed that documentation was copied from `list` method and that parameter cannot be used with `watch` method and they're going to update docs of `watch` method in API reference. (However it's still there).