# Google Admin SDK push notification, watch requests stopped working last Friday

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-admin-sdk

We have been using Admin SDK Push Notifications successfully for a long time (several years). Now suddenly the channel subscription or "watch request" stopped working in 3 different projects at the same time. We are loosing user data updates from all our customers all the time now. So this is a critical service outage. What can we do?

The exception is this. There has not been changes to our configuration or code regarding this. The app-id and details are omitted from the webhook URL in that snippet. It is anyway in format like https://...[app-id].appspot.com

```
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://...[app-id].appspot.com",
    "reason" : "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized"
  } ],
  "message" : "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://...[app-id].appspot.com"
}
```

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push

Comment: Maybe the SSL certificate (or the CA) is not trusted anymore?

Comment: You can try reading inputs from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928758/google-push-notifications-unauthorized-webhook-callback-channel). It seems there are different solutions for the problem and there's no guarantee what would work for you. In this case, OP did not do anything and it got fixed by itself.

Comment: The webhook we have been using is like [app-id].appspot.com and it has been like that for several years. Our suspect is that something has changed in GCP and the appspot.com domains stopped working last Friday. This problem started like said in 3 different projects (at same day) that use push-notifications with slightly different setups.

Comment: Is there any explanation why this started to happen without notice! I am targeting my question to Google Cloud Platform? This was *not* a misconfiguration on our side, we had to suddenly figure out a workaround for this!!!

Comment: @JariK did you manage to fix it? I'm facing the same issue. After all the domain verifications, I get the same error with an [app-id].appspot.com webhook...

Comment: @cjlallana After all we never got it working with [app-id].appspot.com had to use custom domain public URL which our project luckily supports and register that in the same way.