# google drive API verified domain not working with changes watch

Tags: google-drive-api

According to https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch,
you need an `https` address to make it works if you need to watch over a change of resources.

I've configured the domain successfully by going to Google Cloud Console > Domain Verification > Add Domain.

[image]

Then I use Postman to make a call to test it:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch?pageToken=nextPageToken

```json
{
//   "kind": "api#channel",
  "id": "1234231",
  "expiration": 1656402233000,
  "type": "webhook",
  "payload": true,
  "address": "https://mrnoc.blogspot.com",
  "params": {
      "pageToken": "nextPageToken"
  }
}
```

However, it failed and generated this error message:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
                "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://mrnoc.blogspot.com"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://mrnoc.blogspot.com"
    }
}
```

I have no idea how it doesn't work, I've tried to look around but it a dead end as it seems like I've configured everything properly.

Please help if you know what might stop it from working.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52093708/14606046) if this could resolve your issue?

Comment: @RonM yes, I've tried that but I couldn't verify the domain.